# Dynamic.Linq Building generic Where Condition

Tags: linq

I have been using System.Linq.Dynamic library. Is there a way to use Entities with one to many relationship. To be specific 
I have 3 classes

```
class A
{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  ...
  ...

  public Class2 class2 {get;set;}

  public ICollection<Another> Bs{get;set;}

}
class Class2
{
   public int Id{get;set;}
}
class Another
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
}
```

I can filter when the relationship is one to one

```
public IQueryable<T> Select<T>(string condition,object value)
{
 var list=FindAll<T>();//return list of T from database
 var result=list.Where(string.Format("{0} = @0",condition),value);
}

result=Select<A>("class2.Id",1);
```

the above call gives me the list of A objects whose class2's id=1.
how can i search if the relationship is one to many..
how do i filter list of A objects based on each object's first item of Bs ie Bs[0].
would it be possible to filter using Linq.Dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not directly possible to filter on the first item of a collection relation (such as `Bs[0]`), for one because `ICollection<B>` does not have an indexer.

However, it is possible to use predicates such as `Any` in a Dynamic Linq expression, such as:

```
result = list.Where("Bs.Any(Id = @0)", value);
```

which is equivalent to

```
result = from a in list 
         where a.Bs.Any(b => b.Id == value) 
         select a;
```

(This translates to an `EXISTS` query in SQL.)

I think that's what you're after, not `Bs[0]`.

---

The full list of supported predicates and aggregates for System.Linq.Dynamic seems to be:

- **Where**(*condition*)
- **Any**() and **Any**(*condition*)
- **All**(*condition*)
- **Count**() and **Count**(*condition*)
- **Max**(*selector*)
- **Min**(*selector*)
- **Sum**(*selector*)
- **Average**(*selector*)

For `Bs[0].Id = @0` you'd need to have support for **First**(*condition*), which you could add to a private copy of System.Linq.Dynamic, by editing the interface `IEnumerableSignatures`, adding

```
void First();
void First(bool predicate);
void FirstOrDefault();
void FirstOrDefault(bool predicate);
```

(Adding Last(OrDefault) and Single(OrDefault) as well would be a logical step IMHO.)